# How are textures mapped by the persp3d function of the rgl package in R?

Tags: r

I am trying map an image onto a sphere, following this example in the persp3d documentation:

```
lat <- matrix(seq(90,-90, len=50)*pi/180, 50, 50, byrow=TRUE)
long <- matrix(seq(-180, 180, len=50)*pi/180, 50, 50)

r <- 6378.1 # radius of Earth in km
x <- r*cos(lat)*cos(long)
y <- r*cos(lat)*sin(long)
z <- r*sin(lat)

open3d()
persp3d(x, y, z, col="white", 
       texture=system.file("textures/worldsmall.png",package="rgl"), 
       specular="black", axes=FALSE, box=FALSE, xlab="", ylab="", zlab="",
       normal_x=x, normal_y=y, normal_z=z)
```

I will eventually want to add objects on specific points on the sphere, and so need to know what pixel coordinates in the image file correspond to what x,y,z (or lat, long) values. In other words, what map projection is persp3d assuming of worldsmall.png? (I am not expecting it to map nicely onto a traditional map projection, as persp3d is obviously not limited to spheres, but there's got to be *some* algorithm for converting one set of coordinates to the other.)

Comment: For the record, here is a good starting point:  http://lists.neoscientists.org/pipermail/rgl-general/2006-December/000062.html